# Error "Does not exist in current context"

Tags: c#, razor

I have the following code where depts has already been declared and is a query result of type `IEnumerable<dynamic>`

I am getting an error saying `dept does not exist in the current context`. If I comment out dept.Name there are no errors.

```
@{
  int I = 0;
  for(I=0; I < dropdowndepts.Length; I++){
    var depts = iStar.GetDepts() ;
    <li class="header header_@I">
      foreach(var dept in depts){
        <li>@dept.Name</li>
      }
    </li>
  }
}
```

OK new info, if i break up the loops then it compiles. So the following works:

```
@{
                    int I = 0;
                    string[] dropdowndepts = new string[6]{"Store Logo","Clothing","Footwear","Outerwear","Gear","Deals"} ;
                }
                    @for(I=0; I < dropdowndepts.Length; I++){
                        var depts = iStar.GetDepts() ;
                        @:<li class="header header_@I">
                            <ul>
                            @foreach(var dept in depts){
                                <li>@dept.Name</li>
                            }
                            </ul>
                        @:</li>
                    }
```

Comment: why @dept.Name just use dept.Name

Comment: Where exactly is depts variable declared? At the top of your view or do you have a custom razor view class defined? You need to show more code...

Comment: The IEnumerable from `iStar.GetDepts()` should be part of your Model/ViewModel, and then use `@model.Depts`.  Otherwise, you are tying your view into a call to a method.  The view should just expect an IEnumerable of Depts as part of the model, and not care where it comes from.

Comment: unfortunately didnt get rid of the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second foreach loop is being interpreted as markup.  Put an @ in front of it:

```
@{
  int I = 0;
  for(I=0; I < dropdowndepts.Length; I++){
    var depts = iStar.GetDepts() ;
    <li class="header header_@I">
      @foreach(var dept in depts){
        <li>@dept.Name</li>
      }
    </li>
  }
}
```